# r print next element of a list in a for loop

Tags: r, list, loops

I would like to print the bottle song (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Green_Bottles).

My loop code looks like this:

```
number <- c("Ten", "Nine", "Eight", "Seven", "Six", "Five", "Four", "Three", "Two")
and_if <- ("And if one green bottle should accidentally fall,")

bottles <- function() {
  for (num in number) {
    cat(str_c(rep(num, 2), " green bottles hanging on the wall", collapse = "\n"), "\n", and_if, "\n", "There'll be", number[2], "green bottles hanging on the wall", "\n", "\n")
    if (num == "Two") {
   cat(str_c(rep("One green bottle hanging on the wall", 2), collapse = "\n"), "\n", and_if, "\n", "There'll be no green bottles hanging on the wall", "\n", "\n")     
    }
  }
}

bottles()
```

And the result is this:

```
Ten green bottles hanging on the wall
Ten green bottles hanging on the wall 
 And if one green bottle should accidentially fall, 
 There'll be Nine green bottles hanging on the wall 

Nine green bottles hanging on the wall
Nine green bottles hanging on the wall 
 And if one green bottle should accidentially fall, 
 There'll be Nine green bottles hanging on the wall 

Eight green bottles hanging on the wall
Eight green bottles hanging on the wall 
 And if one green bottle should accidentially fall, 
 There'll be Nine green bottles hanging on the wall
```

... (and so on) ...

```
One green bottle hanging on the wall
One green bottle hanging on the wall 
 and if one green bottle should accidentally fall, 
 There'll be no green bottles hanging on the wall
```

So at the moment it reads "There'll be Nine green bottles hanging on the wall" in the last line of each paragraph (except for the one bottle para). What I would like to have is the next number from the list printed instead of always "Nine". 
I guess you get what I mean.

This doesn't seem super hard, but I just couldn't find the answer.. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you may need to loop over the sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be looped over the sequence and then extract the value based on the index

```
library(stringr)
bottles <- function() {
  for (i in seq_along(number)) {
    cat(str_c(rep(number[i], 2), " green bottles hanging on the wall", collapse = "\n"), "\n", and_if, "\n", "There'll be", replace(number[i+1], is.na(number[i+1]), "no"), "green bottles hanging on the wall", "\n", "\n")
    if (i == length(number)) {
   cat(str_c(rep("One green bottle hanging on the wall", 2), collapse = "\n"), "\n", and_if, "\n", "There'll be no green bottles hanging on the wall", "\n", "\n")     
    }
  }
}

bottles()
```